# How to use a list in another predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, predicate

I am currently trying to solve this problem.

The generator `generate/2` is to produce all valid combinations for a window.

```
generate(Gs,Cs) :-
    colorset(Gs,Cs),
    valid(Gs,Cs). 

?- genere([b,c,d,i,j],C).

C = [red   , yellow, red   , yellow, blue  ] ;
C = [red   , yellow, red   , blue  , yellow] ;
C = [red   , yellow, blue  , yellow, red   ] ;
C = [red   , yellow, blue  , blue  , red   ] ;
C = [red   , yellow, blue  , blue  , yellow] ;
C = [red   , blue  , red   , yellow, blue  ] ;
C = [red   , blue  , red   , blue  , yellow] ;
C = [red   , blue  , yellow, yellow, red   ] ;
C = [red   , blue  , yellow, yellow, blue  ] ;
C = [red   , blue  , yellow, blue  , red   ] ;
C = [yellow, red   , yellow, red   , blue  ] ;
C = [yellow, red   , yellow, blue  , red   ] ;
C = [yellow, red   , blue  , red   , yellow] ;
C = [yellow, red   , blue  , blue  , red   ] ;
C = [yellow, red   , blue  , blue  , yellow] ;
C = [yellow, blue  , red   , red   , yellow] ;
C = [yellow, blue  , red   , red   , blue  ] ;
C = [yellow, blue  , red   , blue  , yellow] ;
C = [yellow, blue  , yellow, red   , blue  ] ;
C = [yellow, blue  , yellow, blue  , red   ] ;
C = [blue  , red   , yellow, red   , blue  ] ;
C = [blue  , red   , yellow, yellow, red   ] ;
C = [blue  , red   , yellow, yellow, blue  ] ;
C = [blue  , red   , blue  , red   , yellow] ;
C = [blue  , red   , blue  , yellow, red   ] ;
C = [blue  , yellow, red   , red   , yellow] ;
C = [blue  , yellow, red   , red   , blue  ] ;
C = [blue  , yellow, red   , yellow, blue  ] ;
C = [blue  , yellow, blue  , red   , yellow] ;
C = [blue  , yellow, blue  , yellow, red   ] ; 
false.
```

I need to the predicate `valid/2`.

Given the predicate colorset which I have defined as following.

```
colorset([],[]).

colorset([_|Nodes], [C|Color]):- color(C), colorset(Nodes, Colors).
```

Right now, I am trying to figure out if there's a way to generate the colorset predicate first and then check if the adjacent nodes have the same colour but I am not sure if that's possible in Prolog?

What is another alternative?

Comment: `if that's possible in prolog?` I didn't look at this in detail, but Prolog is great at generating data sets.

Comment: Your expected results aren't clear, but sure, it's most likely possible to define `colorset` to give too many results, and define `valid` to filter them out. Though it might be faster for large problems of the type to check partial results as you go, to "prune the tree".

Comment: @aschepler How would I call the multiple possible lists I made in colorset in the valid predicate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - it looks like you have one list of colors at a time.